# IBM Notes Designer 9 - Preview in Notes

Tags: xpages, preview

Does anyone else got the problem that you cannot preview an XPage from the "Preview in Notes" toolbar button w/o getting the error "404 The requested resource cannot be located"?
When I set the XPage as "launch option" for the application I can load it in the Client.
Yes, I have "build automatically" activated. In the browser it also works as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me.

XPiNC can sometimes cache application settings where XPages is involved. Try "Clear Private Data" from the Refresh drop-down button. Alternatively, I've sometimes needed to close and re-open Notes to pick up changes.

My preferred mode of development is to use a browser and just use XPiNC for a final check.

Comment: Yes, I tried to clear the cache several times. It's strange that the page will load when I set it as the default launch option.

Comment: Are you trying to preview a server-based NSF or local? Mine was server-based.

Comment: The database is server based

Comment: Addition: I also noticed that in Designer 8.5.3FP3 today - strange, but I never experienced this before...

Comment: Same application? It may be worth cleaning the project.

Comment: I've found that if I make my design changes in a template and refresh the design on the server, it seems to 'clear the cache' and allow me to use recently made changes in XPinC. It's annoying, but the good thing is that it is forcing my team to use templates more!

Comment: I fear you got me wrong: there is nothing special with this application, I also did a project clean. It's just the preview action in DD that doesn't work for me here. I start with an empty database, created s single sinple xpage (also empty) and clicked on "preview in notes". Then this error occurs. "Preview in browser" is ok and also the page is loaded when I set it as the launch page for the client in the database properties.

I think I will return to what Paul said: preview in browser only.